# Paypal Digital Goods - How to retrieve payer info?

Tags: paypal

I just integrated the express checkout script from https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmacole/another-digital-goods-demo into my site.

I have a question. I'd like to keep track of all the sales with Freshbooks and I was wondering if it's possible to get the payer's information after the payment has been sent.

I think I read somewhere that since it's a "digital goods" type checkout, it doesn't involve any address stuff.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
- Alain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What information are you looking for? If it's any address-related information that would be correct; this is not collected with a Digital Goods checkout which, as the name implies, if intended to sell digital goods.

If all you need is the fancy popup, I'd suggest looking at Embedded Payments which is part of the Adaptive suite of API's. See https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro "Using Embedded Payments".

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert!I am not interested in their physical address. I would like to get their name and email. Any other additional info would be great too, but not required. Can that be done?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you're using Digital Goods for Express Checkout, this information is returned in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API response.
See also https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetExpressCheckoutDetails